# Correct way to execute events on certain routes / pages using Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Project is in Laravel.

I have one app.js file in which I initiate my components and have methods to e.g. populate select boxes with values. Let's say I have a size selection box and a colour selection box, however, both are on different pages.

It does not make sense to fetch the data for the select boxes all at once, just fetch the data trough Ajax when the page is requested that has the selection box on it.

However what would be the correct approach on this?

So if the URL would be https://localhost/color the Ajax request call to the API to fetch the colour parameters would be executed. If the URL would be https://localhost/sizes the Ajax request call to the API to fetch the sizes parameters would be executed.

I would think: have watch look at a route or perhaps on mounted/created look at what the route is at that moment.

Comment: Are you using Vue Router?

Comment: @YomS. I dont use it yet... but if it solves my question I would.

Comment: I think it's worth the try. With Vue Router, you would assign a view component to a route/path (`/color` or `/sizes`) and decide therein which API to call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vue Router, you could put a `beforeRouteEnter()` [route guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) in the component. The router will call this whenever the user navigates to the route which displays that component. Alternatively, you could fetch the data in the page components `mounted()` method.

Comment: Dub question perhaps. it also works if the routing is done through Laravel? So it triggers whenever a page is loaded?

Comment: Do you mean like if you're displaying the different components within separate blade templates? If you load the data in the lifecycle hook, that'll work in that scenario.